# Nginx reverse proxy works only for landing page, any other links won't work

Tags: nginx

I have a reverse proxy for `/forums` setup like so:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
        location /forums {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

                proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:4567/;
                proxy_redirect off;

                # Sockect.IO Support
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
}
```

It works, kind of, when I try to go to `localhost/forums` I see the page, but all the static content 404's and if I try to click on a link, e.g. /login it takes me to `localhost/login` instead of `localhost/forums/login`, any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without going into the nginx configuration details:
does your forum application know that its root url is now localhost/forums?  and not "localhost/"?